# How to raise an error on duplicate column slug in FriendlyId?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, friendly-id

I use friendly_id gem and if my slug column have duplicate value, gem updates it by adding a unique key. I want raise error `already been taken`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems friendly_id(v5.2.4) does not have an option to avoid setting the UUID when a slug conflict happens. So the best way to solve this it to redefine the [method responsible for resolving the conflict](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/877c096d2eee2aad048e457d7712dce499cebb0d/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L320) and raise an exception.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  def resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  end
end
```